# Sorting a list of dictionary based on a key in C#

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary and I want it sort on the date key in descending order. But the following query gives inappropriate result. Please help.

Date format is DD/MM/YYYY

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> list = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
            Dictionary<string, string> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict1["Date"] = "01/03/2015";
            dict1["Name"] = "bbb";
            list.Add(dict1);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict2["Date"] = "11/08/2014";
            dict2["Name"] = "ccc";
            list.Add(dict2);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict3 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict3["Date"] = "21/03/2014";
            dict3["Name"] = "aaa";
            list.Add(dict3);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict4 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict4["Date"] = "01/01/2015";
            dict4["Name"] = "ddd";
            list.Add(dict4);

var ordered = list.OrderBy(x => x["Date"]);
```

Comment: Each dictionary contains exactly one item ?

Comment: define "inappropriate results". Also, your date is a string, it'll order like a string does

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary when you can use a tuple for the same result?

Comment: Your `Date` param is of type **String** and not `DateTime`. How come you can expect it to sort appropriately?

Comment: Actually raw data is fetched from a SQL SP and the values are stored as a key-value pair. The result is then returned in JSON. Initially, order by was not required. And now it is required but we cannot change the SP for some reason. Since it is stored as a string so the query sorts it as a string. Is there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: You don't need to change the SP. You can still store it in a dictionary of <String,DateTime> which would then sort correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Date` entry in each of your dictionaries is a string, a `List` knows nothing about how to sort strings based on date ordering rules.

One (terrible) option is to convert each string to an appropriate date at the point of ordering it

```
var ordered = list.OrderBy(x => DateTime.ParseExact( x["Date"], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
```

I say terrible option, because having a List of dictionaries seems like a bit of an abusable pattern, you should probably have a List of objects with properties `Name` and `Date` where the `Date` property is actually of type `DateTime`.

Comment: You should provide `IFormatProvider` for `ParseExact` to work.

Comment: Still would not work if the current culture is not OK. This will get a `FormatException` saying. *String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.* Which happens to me while the culture is set to tr-TR at the moment. May I suggest the use of `IFormatProvider` as a parameter?

Comment: Thanks...it is working fine for me. I tried it but I used Convert.ToDateTime rather than DateTime.ParseExact and it was giving me error.